# Google cloud scheduler のGUIで頻度：月末を指定したい

Tags: google-cloud

Google cloud scheduler のGUI上の頻度に関して、
毎月月末日23:59に動くバッジを設定したいと思っています。
試したこととしては、`59 23 L * *`で設定しようとしましたが、
`無効な頻度の形式です。`のエラーとなってしまいます。
どのように設定すればよいでしょうか。

Comment: Googleで使えるか分かりませんが、類似のcron/crontabの記事がこれらでしょう。[Cron job to run on the last day of the month](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6139189/9014308), [Schedule the last day of every month](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/478335), [Cron Job For the Last Day of the Month](https://blog.nexcess.net/2013/05/09/cron-job-for-the-last-day-of-the-month/), [How to setup cron job for last day of month](http://chetnachaudhari.github.io/2016-01-26/cron-for-last-day-of-month/)

Comment: リンクありがとうございます。上記のリンクなのですが、cloud scheduler上ですとバリデーションエラーとなってしまうことを確認しました…。

Comment: まあ難しいのでしょうね。代替手段に毎月1日の午前0時0分を指定するとかは出来るのでしょうか？ 1分の違いが致命的なほど大きくは無いのでは？

Comment: おっしゃる通りですね、一旦相談してみて上記にするようにしました。回答ありがとうございます！